# Quais são os critérios para compilar na versão mínima do Android

Tags: android

Estou desenvolvendo um app e tive que importar um projeto do GitHub como modulo, o zxing, optei importar como modulo ao invés de importar como dependencia porque assim posso editar as classes e desabilitar Boa parte do conteúdo que não vou utilizar. Só que queria abaixar a versão mínima requerida, e gostaria de saber se tem uma lista ou algo do tipo que especifica que tipo de recurso e exigido em determinada versão para que eu possa ver se posso remove-los e abaixar a versão mínima

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Se você utiliza o Visual Studio:**

1. De um duplo clique em `Propriedades(Properties)`
2. Na mesma seção que abrir que seria `Aplication` você vera as versões destinadas da copilação
3. Selecione a Versão minima que deseja copilar e tente um `Build Solution`
4. Caso aconteça algum erro vá na seção `Build` localizada em `Propriedades` do passo 1
5. Marque a opção `Optmize Code` e `Allow Unsafe Code` e tente um `Build Solution` novamente

Caso continue com algum erro durante a copilação provavelmente sera referente a uma falta de suporte da API antiga sobre tal recurso